# Google Sheets - dependant drop down box

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am having an issue as fairly new to googlesheets - I have been asked to make a dependant drop down box which I achieved but when someone tries to drag it down to copy the formula it all goes wrong!!

As I said I am new to script writing and I am very confused as to where I have gone wrong, I used a simple Indirect formula and am out of my depth, if anyone could spend a few minutes helping me I would appreciate it please, I can share the sheet with you, I am desperate to learn and people will probably laugh at something so simple but we all have to start somewhere, thanks

Comment: We'd love to help but without any code that's impossible. Please do provide the indirect formula and if possible share (a copy of) your sheet.

Comment: Sorry I thought it had copied over, thank you all but I have now solved the problem